# nginx location blocks wrongly executed

Tags: caching, nginx

I'm hosting an angular2 app behind nginx reverse proxy. Angular2 is technically one single page application, hosted in index.html, but it's using normal routes, so the index.html file is not requested directly, instead a normal looking route could be requested like:

- `http://my.angular.app/`
- `http://my.angular.app/users`
- `http://my.angular.app/users/john`
- `http://my.angular.app/resource123`
- `http://my.angular.app/anything`

depending, if there is a file on the route, I want to serve the file (and cache it). Otherwise I want to serve index.html. These are my 3 location blocks:

```
# don't cache index.html file
location / {
    index index.html;
    expires -1;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

# Cache everything with a hash for a year
location ~* "\.[0-9a-f]{16,999}(?:\.chunk|\.bundle|)\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$" {
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";

    access_log        off;
    expires           31536000; # 1 year
}

# Cache all other assets for a day
location ~* ^(?!index\.html$).*\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";

    access_log off;
    expires 86400; # 1 day
}
```

My intent is to never let the browser cache the index.html file, but everything else should be cached as long as possible. The part with hashed files works fine. The problem is for normal URLs

if I request `my.angular.app/module/sub-route` I still receive a caching header for 1 day although the 3. location shouldn't match (no extension defined) and the first location has `expires -1` set.

Comment: How about stuffing `index.html` into an own location and set your cache settings accordingly. Defining that location before your last and using `=` instead of `~*`. Like `location = /index.html`. If that block matches the `=` will make shure, no other location will get evaluated after that.

Comment: @ansi_lumen sry I forgo to elaborate on Angular2 hosting issues. Because Angular2 is using normal URLs (without the hash like many other SPA frameworks are using it) the client rarely requests index.html, but usually a random route which doesn't exist on the server. I need to detect this and serve index.html. (see updated question)

Comment: The third location matches `/index.html` because you have missed the leading `/`. All `nginx` URIs include a leading `/`.

Comment: @RichardSmith you're absolutely right, what I actually wanted to write is probably something like `^(?!.*index\.html$).*\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$` - if you'll write the comment as an answer I'd accept it. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `nginx` URIs begin with a leading `/`.

Your negative assertion `^(?!index\.html$)` will not reject the URI `/index.html`, which means that `/index.html` will match the third `location` block.